# Building CSS::LESS on OS X

Tags: macos, perl

Anyone successfully installed [CSS::LESS](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CSS-LESS/README.pod) on OS X?

For me it failed with many errors, like the next one:

```
$ make test
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1 test
t/00.load.t ................. 1/1 # Testing CSS::LESS 0.0.3
t/00.load.t ................. ok
t/10.dry-run.t ..............
    #   Failed test '"include_paths" parameter (set to constructor)'
    #   at t/10.dry-run.t line 20.
    #                   'lessc /var/folders/7l/nhyscwy14bjb_sxr_t2gynpm0000gn/T/RoPSlWoxEQ --include-path=/Users/me/.cpanm/work/1395039258.75205/CSS-LESS-v0.0.3/t/foo/:/bar/ --verbose --no-color'
    #     doesn't match '(?^:^lessc /tmp/\w+ --include-path=/Users/me/.cpanm/work/1395039258.75205/CSS-LESS-v0.0.3/t/foo/:/bar/ --verbose --no-color$)'
```

IMHO, this is a case of a wrong test expectations, because on OS X the `tempfiles` are created in the `/var/folders/....` and not in the `/tmp`.

Similar error reports are in the [www.cpantesters.org](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/C/CSS-LESS.html?grade=1&perlmat=2&patches=2&oncpan=1&distmat=1&perlver=ALL&osname=darwin&version=v0.0.3) .  **EXPECT ONE** here: http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/dac3ce8e-3c79-11e3-aac4-3cf3dfeaf78b

Asking this question because if it is **somewhat** possible build the CSS::LESS os OS X would be happy to know - how.

## EDIT

Hm, the above successful test report (and the Module itself) is strange, because

```
# Testing CSS::LESS 0.0.3
t/00.load.t ................. ok
t/10.dry-run.t .............. ok
t/90.lessc_compile.t ........ skipped: Not installed lessc
t/91.lessc_compile_error.t .. skipped: Not installed lessc
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - the module DEPENDS on 'lessc'

t/92.lessc_not-installed.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=5, Tests=8,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.02 sys +  0.29 cusr  0.06 csys =  0.40 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

but, regardless of the missing `lessc` (what should be an error, because the module **depends** on it) the test

```
t/10.dry-run.t .............. ok
```

finished as `OK` - and on my system throws an error.

---

If someone care, my `perl -V`

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=13.0.0, archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
    uname='darwin medvedik.local 13.0.0 darwin kernel version 13.0.0: thu sep 19 22:22:27 pdt 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6release_x86_64 x86_64 '
    config_args='-de -Dprefix=/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3 -Dcc=clang -Duse64bitall -Dusethreads -DDEBUGGING -Dusemultiplicity -Accflags=-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Aeval:scriptdir=/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='clang', ccflags ='-fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -no-cpp-precomp -arch x86_64 -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include',
    optimize='-O3 -g',
    cppflags='-no-cpp-precomp -arch x86_64 -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -no-cpp-precomp -arch x86_64 -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 cc -arch x86_64', ldflags =' -arch x86_64 -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /opt/local/lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lgdbm -ldbm -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    libc=, so=dylib, useshrplib=false, libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags=' -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: DEBUGGING HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV
                        PERL_TRACK_MEMPOOL PERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV
                        USE_64_BIT_ALL USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS
                        USE_LARGE_FILES USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE
                        USE_LOCALE_CTYPE USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO
                        USE_PERL_ATOF USE_REENTRANT_API
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Jan  6 2014 16:00:02
  %ENV:
    PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION="0.67"
    PERLBREW_HOME="/Users/me/.perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_MANPATH="/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/man"
    PERLBREW_PATH="/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin"
    PERLBREW_PERL="perl-5.16.3"
    PERLBREW_ROOT="/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_VERSION="0.67"
  @INC:
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl/5.16.3
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3
    .
```

system:

```
Darwin marvin.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

compiler/gcc:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: `/var/folders/7l/nhyscwy14bjb_sxr_t2gynpm0000gn/T/RoPSlWoxEQ` doesn't match `m{/tmp/\w+}`. Seems like it wanted to test it got the arguments right, and made some assumptions about the location of your tmp folder. Or maybe your temp folder is a symlink and that confuses the test. It could very well be a bad test, but I can't look into it right now.

Comment: @ikegami on _every_ OS X (default installation) the `/tmp` is a symlink to `private/tmp`. But partially found how make a "successful" test report. But the successful in this case mean skipped tests... - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself a partial answer for the question.

The test is probably *somewhat* depends on the `$TMPDIR` shell variable. On OS X **defaultly** this wariable points to an directory what is unique to every logged user, and resides in the `/var/folders/...`, like this:

```
$ echo $TMPDIR
/var/folders/7l/nhyscwy14bjb_sxr_t2gynpm0000gn/T/
```

When manually changed the default value of `$TMPDIR` to `/tmp`, with:

```
TMPDIR=/tmp/
```

and run for CSS::LESS

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
```

got

```
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1 test
t/00.load.t ................. 1/1 # Testing CSS::LESS 0.0.3
t/00.load.t ................. ok   
t/10.dry-run.t .............. ok   
t/90.lessc_compile.t ........ 2/? 
#   Failed test 'LESS compile test with compress'
#   at t/90.lessc_compile.t line 19.
#          got: 'a{border-bottom:solid 3px #000}div{width:100px}a:link{color:#1a1a1a}'
#     expected: 'a{border-bottom:solid 3px #000}
# div{width:100px}
# a:link{color:#1a1a1a}
# '
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3.
t/90.lessc_compile.t ........ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/3 subtests 
t/91.lessc_compile_error.t .. ok   
t/92.lessc_not-installed.t .. ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/90.lessc_compile.t      (Wstat: 256 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=5, Tests=15,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.02 sys +  1.46 cusr  0.35 csys =  1.88 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/5 test programs. 1/15 subtests failed.
make: *** [test] Error 255
```

The subtest

```
t/10.dry-run.t .............. ok
```

is no problem anymore. Anyway the module didn't built - but throws another (lessc) error.

So, Neil Bower (a sumbitter of the "successful" test report) probably changed the `$TMPDIR` too. And because he hasn't installed the external command `lessc` got a successful result.

Demostration:

```
$ sudo mv /opt/local/bin/{lessc,lessc1}    #rename lessc to lessc1
Password:

$ make test
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1 test
t/00.load.t ................. 1/1 # Testing CSS::LESS 0.0.3
t/00.load.t ................. ok   
t/10.dry-run.t .............. ok   
t/90.lessc_compile.t ........ skipped: Not installed lessc
t/91.lessc_compile_error.t .. skipped: Not installed lessc
t/92.lessc_not-installed.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=5, Tests=8,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.03 sys +  0.56 cusr  0.11 csys =  0.77 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Great :) - unfortunately - this is a FALSE result, and the `CSS::LESS` didn't builds OK on OS X.

Comment: So the original failure is a bad test. Since it works regardless of the value of TMPDIR, it shouldn't be checking that TMPDIR starts with `/tmp/`. Ignoring it shouldn't be a problem. This new failure does sound like a legitimate failure, though.